# How do I generate 1000 data points?

Tags: python, noise

I am a bit confused since I am trying to learn python.

My question is how can I generate 1000 datapoints for a noisy S-curve and then save it to a .txt file?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You may consider using the `random` module to generate a large list of random values

```py
COUNT = 1000  # Number of data points 

UPPER_BOUND = 100 # The domain they occupy, exclusive at the upper bound
LOWER_BOUND = 0

data_points = []
for _ in range(COUNT):
    data_points.append(random.randint(LOWER_BOUND, UPPER_BOUND))
```

To save this to a text file, use the `open()` method with the `"w"` value to **w**rite into a file:

```py
with open("filename.txt", "w") as  f:
    f.write(data_points)
```

The use of the `with` clause removes the need to call `close()` on the file after it is used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`scipy.stats.logistic`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.logistic.html) for the "S-shaped" curve and [`numpy.random.uniform`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) for the noise:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import logistic

N = 1000

x = np.linspace(-10,10, num=N)
noise = np.random.uniform(0, 0.1, size=N)
points = logistic.cdf(x)+noise

np.savetxt('points.txt', points)
```

content of points.txt (first lines):

```
5.163273718724530059e-02
2.404908177729772611e-02
7.221953948290879555e-02
3.023476195714707923e-02
4.972362503720893084e-02
8.986980537557204274e-02
9.878733026764449643e-02
9.584209234526251675e-02
7.709992266714442433e-02
1.367468690439026940e-02
```

How the data looks like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, points)
```

[image: noisy sigmoid]